# How to fill in the parameters for kernel density estimation?

Tags: qgis, raster, density

I am desperately trying to calculate animals home range with kernel. Unfortunately, the result is obviously incorrect and I cannot identify my mistake (I would like to post a screenshot but its not allowed to me yet).

Is there an instruction how to fill in the parameters for kernel density estimation?

Is there a concept how the attribute table has to look like? (I have three columns: ID, longitude, latitude in decimal degrees)

Using QGIS 1.8

Comment: You shouldn't be using geographic coordinates for this purpose: project your data first.  (This is discussed in the answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/50791/664.)  That may in itself resolve your problem, because then the kernel radius/half-width/bandwidth will be measured in meaningful units. It might also help to have an intuitive grasp of KDE.  Although this thread mentions ArcMap, its answers apply to any GIS: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14374/interpretation-of-arcgis-kernel-density-legend-parameters.

Comment: You ask many questions, all of which have been asked and answered here: please search our site.

Comment: I now understand that I have to transform my geographic coordinates into UTM in order to calculate kernel with the plugin ANIMOVE. but i cannot find a solution how to do this (in QGIS, in excel??) PLEASE can somebody help me!

Comment: As whuber recommended I searched the forum for an explanation how to project geographic longitude/latitude data into UTM in order to calculate kernel, but there is none! its very dissapointing that people are not willing to help. thank you very much!!

Comment: Really? A search on [projection UTM](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=projection+UTM) gets over 300 hits, but you find none of them helpful?